# Margin whenever there is a line break (not via line-height, not via paragraphs)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, styled-components

I need to define a specific margin, whenever there is a **line break**; This needs to be specific to the element, e.g. `h1, h2` etc. so I cannot just put a style into `<br/>`, since that would affect all elements the same. The design I'm working on defines a specific line-height as well as a specific margin between paragraphs (`<p>`-tags), so I cannot use any of these either.

Are there any solutions for use cases like these?

Comment: I don't get why you can't use line-height just for the h1, h2 and keep the paragraphs with the specific margin/line-height you need. Use the right hierarchy and you won't have any problem.

Comment: Yeah I might have been a bit unclear. The problem is not just with `h1,h2`, but with all elements, so my `p`s have a specific line-height, margin, & margin when there is a manual line break;

Comment: You should add some examples because it's not clear what you're asking.